# Extract date from date time in the format 2015-01-01-15:00:02:30

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract only date from a timestamp of the following type:

```
2015-01-01-15:00:02:30
```

I tried only using cast() but it gave me an error:

```
':' is undefined symbol
```

Can I get some assistance here? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cast(val as date)` should work.

Comment: That is not the error message if converting that string to a date, time or datetime. Perhaps you can share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `convert()` and `left()`

```
select convert(date,left('2015-01-01-15:00:02:30',10))
```

Comment: thank you Sir for your help.appreciate that. I did not know about the left() function earlier. thanx for teaching me something new and useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(left('2015-01-01-15:00:02:30',10) as date)
```

Comment: [@]kegs88 thanx for the help Sir. One more thing I wanted to learn was; if I want to insert this value to a table while creating a table what data type shall I define this column as?

Comment: @jayant I would use Date since that is the datatype you are casting the value as into the table.

Comment: thanx for the advice.